# Java Web Application on startup

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, init

Is there a way to execute java code, when a Java EE (Java web project) starts up (or receives a first request)? I know that servlets have `init()` methods, but is there such method for an entire application?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have a class that

```
implements ServletContextListener
```

and in your web.xml

```
<listener>
    <listener-class> myPackage.MyServletContextListener </listener-class>
</listener>
```

see http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html

and override

```
void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce)
```

Comment: What method should be called? When will it be called? on startup, or first request?

Comment: Upon loading of the context (i.e. at startup or deployment)